# Is there a way to list current processes using Qt on windows?

Tags: windows, qt, qt4

Is it possible to know which processes are running using Qt 4? I'm looking for a way to wait until an application is closed by the user to make an operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know a Qt solution either. But doing it is not that hard using the`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`, `Process32FirstW()` and `Process32NextW()` functions. Just search the MSDN for this. There is also a (IMO too complex) example on

[Taking a snapshot and viewing processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686701(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Not really a Qt4 solution, but you could start [WMIC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) in a [QProcess](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qprocess.html) and evaluate the result.

Something like :

```
wmic process get name /every:5
```