# Find a process by name and kill it

Tags: windows, qt, process, kill

I have a Qt based updater application that needs to replace a running process with the new file. On Windows, the updater is failing when the process is running.

Is there a way that I can find a process by name e.g, Firefox.exe and kill it using Qt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to find the running process and kill the process in QT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538967/how-to-find-the-running-process-and-kill-the-process-in-qt)

Comment: [Is there a way to list current processes using Qt on windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833113/is-there-a-way-to-list-current-processes-using-qt-on-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no API to do this in Qt, which means the only way to do it is using platform specific code.

Answer (score 3):

You can call system like this:
taskkill /f /im firefox.exe

Comment: -1 This approach doesn't use Qt, therefore is not a cross-platform solution.

Comment: Qt is cross-platform. I don't know any feature that Qt provides that only exists on Windows. Can you remember any?

Comment: I read question again and you are right - no way to kill process by Qt.